# What is -2loglikelihood?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I don't understand the term "loglikelihood"? I'd like to have a practical understanding of this word, and of why this is important. Besides this whenever we calculate some statistic like chisquare or doing logistic regression, why we take `-2loglikelihood`? What is the significance of $-2$ over here?

If someone can explain in plain simple language, it would be great.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343093/what-is-log-likelihood) on Stack Overflow, but I could not properly understood it.

Thanks very much in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this in mind.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

I think the 'reason' comes from central limit theorem. The statistic $D$ in the link is asymptotically distributed as Chi squared, but when you take log of a normal density function, you get

$$\log (\sqrt{2\pi}) + \frac{1}{2} x^2$$

Note the constant cancels from subtraction but is there a factor of 1/2 in front of $x^2$, multipling 2 gets rid of it.

The - sign is only a convention. If you did loglikelihood of alternative hypothesis - loglikelihood of null, then there is no minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Loglikelihood, like its name suggests, is the natural logarithm of the likelihood. It is useful in maximum likelihood estimation because it reduces a product of N likelihoods to a sum of N loglikelihoods, with is easier to optimize analytically, and usually numerically as well.

The 2 in the above formula for hypothesis tests is abased on the asymptotic distribution of the likelihood ratio statistic (as noted by Lost1 above). 2ln($\frac{L(H_a)}{L(H_0)})\dot\sim \chi^2_1$. This was proved by Wilk's and is called the Wilk's likelihood ratio statistic. See this for [theoretical basis](http://www.math.umd.edu/~slud/s701.S14/WilksThm.pdf). The minus sign is a convention based on what is in the numerator and denominator of the likelihood ratio (i.e., you want BIG values to lead to rejection, so adjust the sense as needed).